# Regex to find date format from a string

Tags: python, regex, date

I have different paths where I have to find the date from the path using regex and append it to filename.

```
Input:

/hash/20190811T003013/ABC.txt

Expected Output:
ABC_20190811T003013.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = '/hash/20190811T003013/ABC.txt'
re.findall('(\w+).txt', s)[0] + '_' + re.findall('(\d{8}\w+)', s)[0] + re.findall('(\.\w+)', s)[0]
'ABC_20190811T003013.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the using `str.join` with `map` and `str.split`:

```
s = '/hash/20190811T003013/ABC.txt'
_, b, c, d = s.split('/')
print('_'.join(d.split('.')[0], c) + '.txt')
```

Output:

```
ABC_20190811T003013.txt
```

Comment: How about making it more generalised instead of looking for the position of the date in the file path @U11-Forward

Comment: @hashalluring Ok i will edit

Comment: @hashalluring Edited my answer